# alert not displaying in JS

Tags: javascript, validation, alert

alert is not working as expected! i don't know why...
I am trying to evaluate a form on client side. I have tried getElementsById, getElementsByName.
Where am i going wrong?
I am sure the flow of control goes through validate()
an alert statement immediately inside validate method is being displayed!

Here is my code:

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" errorPage="Error.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value.indexof('@');
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var rpass = document.getElementById("rpass").value;
    submitOK = true;

    if (uname.length == 0) {
      alert("Username cannot be empty")
      submitOK = false;
    }
    if (email == -1) {
      alert("Not a valid email");
      submitOK = false;
    }
    if (pass.length === 0) {
      alert("Password cannot be empty");
      submitOK = false;
    }
    if (pass != rpass) {
      alert("passwords don't match");
      submitOK = false;
    }
    return submitOK;
  }
</script>
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register</h1>
<br />
<form action="RegInt.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
Enter UserName : <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" value='${ param.uname}'placeholder="Enter Name" ><br/><br/>
Enter Email:     <input type="email" name="email" id = "email" value='${param.email}'placeholder="Enter Email"><br/><br/>
Enter Password:  <input type="password" name="pass" id = "pass" value='${param.pass}'placeholder="Enter password"><br/><br/>
Repeat Password: <input type="password" name="rpass" id = "rpass" value='${param.rpass}'placeholder="Repeat Password"/><br/>
    <br/><br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<h4>${errorMsg}</h4>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you call your function... `validate()`? And also make sure the encoding is right.

Comment: First of all, you should provide some context. Where are the inputs you are trying to validate?

Use https://jsfiddle.net/, show some html, please.

Comment: I did. onsubmit = "return validate()"

Comment: as i noticed you have some typos. alret() should be alert()

Comment: So you edited your post to include all my changes. Did it work or do you still have issues?

Comment: Still the very same issue.

Comment: all the validations happen on server side

Comment: If you run my code in my snippet, you will see it works. You also misspelled indexOf

Comment: Sir... Thank a lot... once i corrected "indexOf", everything is working perfectly

Comment: Please next time add changes as an update since the question now is very confusing now there is only one spelling mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Spelling of alret and indexOf !
2. getElementById is singular
3. submitOK="false" sets submitOK to true since a non-empty string is truthy. use `submitOK=false`
4. you did not return submitOK when you asked the question

```js
    function validate() {
      var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
      var email = document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf('@');
      var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
      var rpass = document.getElementById("rpass").value;
      submitOK = true;

      if (uname.length == 0) {
        alert("Username cannot be empty")
        submitOK = false;
      }
      if (email == -1) {
        alert("Not a valid email");
        submitOK = false;
      }
      if (pass.length === 0) {
        alert("Password cannot be empty");
        submitOK = false;
      }
      if (pass != rpass) {
        alert("passwords don't match");
        submitOK = false;
      }
      return submitOK;
    }
```

```html
<h1>Register</h1>
<br />
<form action="RegInt.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  Enter UserName :
  <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" value='${ param.uname}' placeholder="Enter Name">
  <br/>
  <br/>Enter Email:
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value='${param.email}' placeholder="Enter Email">
  <br/>
  <br/>Enter Password:
  <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value='${param.pass}' placeholder="Enter password">
  <br/>
  <br/>Repeat Password:
  <input type="password" name="rpass" id="rpass" value='${param.rpass}' placeholder="Repeat Password" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -3):

First check the spelling s and correct them. Then comment all the feilds and start troubleshooting them line by line. You will win. Regards !

Comment: That is not an answer. Please wait until you have enough rep to comment

Comment: What are you talking about?