# getElementByName() for date

Tags: javascript, date-comparison

I am trying to evaluate inputs on client side using javascript. The `getElementByName()` method is working for text type inputs. But I want to compare two dates using JS. But `getElementByName()` is not working for date type inputs!
Someone please help!
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    var startdate = document.getElementByName("startdate").valueOf();
    alert(startdate);
    var enddate = document.getElementByName("enddate").value;
    submitOK=true;
    if(startdate>enddate)
        {
            alert("start date should not be greater than end date");
            submitOK=false;
        }
    return submitOK;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you bother to take a look at the console? You could see an error message, since  `document.getElementByName` method doesn't exist. Then read the docs about [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)... Also I'm sure `getElementByName` method doesn't work for test type inputs.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `getElementById()`?

Comment: Re what Teemu said: All modern browsers have fully-featured debuggers/"developer tools" built into them. One of the things that debugger includes is a console where errors are shown. You access these tools via the menus, or by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I (or F12). That console will have the error message Teemu mentioned, and once you've cleared that, the other tools there (including the ability to watch your code run, line by line), will help you *tremendously*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602245/alert-not-displaying-in-js?noredirect=1#comment53058802_32602245

Comment: someone corrected me yesterday!

Comment: @RaghuN: I don't know what your link is meant to indicate, but again, there is no `getElementByName`. There is `getElementById`, and `getElementsByName` (note it's "elements", plural), `getElementsByTagName`, and `querySelectorAll`, and `querySelector`, and (on some browsers) `getElementsByClassName`, but not `getElementByName`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe he meant https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName ? as Teemu said.

Comment: @SecularKid: Oops, left that one off the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get started quickly, add unique ids to both your date inputs, and then use

```
document.getElementById("startdate").value;
```

for example to get both values.
And then regarding of their format, a string comparison can be enough (I don't know because you did not mention anything about that), or then you could do something like

```
var endDate = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
endDate = new Date(endDate);
```

That will give you access to date specific methods that can be handy.
More on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date).